# Drag & Drop in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

How do we add drag & drop functionality in Xamarin..

After lot of googling I found the following official link for drag & drop for xamarin..

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-supporting-drag-and-drop-in-an-app/

But it uses the android native code only.

**My questions:**

1. In Xamarin is it possible to implement drag & drop functionality without native codes?
2. If answer - No -> How do we achieve the drag & drop listeners for all platforms?

I searched google & the official forum and nothing found.. Someone help me..Thanks..

Comment: More than one week eagerly waiting.. No support from xamarin team.. feel sad :(

Comment: did you manage to create a solution for `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: @DennisSchröer I create a customize library for Drag & drop. But we drop the Xamarin app development. so it uncompleted (80% done). If you want this code share your mail id.

Comment: That would be really nice from you! My email is Dennis.Schroeer@gmx.net

Comment: @DennisSchröer chk your mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020 it looks like we have it. You still need to set up DragAndDrop_Experimental flag.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop

Answer (score 5):

Please check the below links,may it helps you.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/touch/drag_rotate_image/

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6521/how-to-perform-drag-and-drop-functionality

https://pumpingco.de/blog/adding-drag-and-drop-to-your-android-application-with-xamarin/

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms does not appear to support that kind of touch. Event handlers for on touch would have to be written in the native implementations with a dependency injection pattern for accessing them from the shared code.

The only built in gestures recognized are tap, pinch and pan.

Using the below link it should not be too difficult to get drag and drop up and running.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/touch/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/

Comment: Clint Landry could you give sample code for drag & drop demo.. I added bounty worth 100 reputation.. If you update the sample code I will give the bounty to you & accept your answer..

Comment: I was able to achieve drag & drop functionality between a pair of lists through Xamarin.Forms and the Pan gesture.  However I took advantage of [Mr. Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/) to make my life easier with touch down events.  I am happy to write up how I did it with some sample code if you are ok with using the Mr. Gestures library.

Comment: I will but it may be a little bit, publishes this week.

Comment: ok.. no problem..bounty end in 6 days.. so please answer before bounty time end..

Comment: @JacobShanley could you provide your solution? I'm interested in using MR Gestures for this purpose.