# Splash screen with animation and delay

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to code a splash screen which, after clicking in a presentation´s image start to do an animation (over the image) and, 5 seconds after, go to a Login page.

I tried to find the solution of it, but the answer use to be related with a specific plataform.

My idea is to code it over cross plataform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching, I found the solution coming from Xamarin offical page (animation´s samples) and another page (for the delay) I don´t remember the site...

I´m posting this question and answer because I think could be really interesting for the community.

```
           Button startButton = new Button() { Image = "splashlogo.png", BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent, HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.Center, Scale = 3.5};

            startButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                var parentAnimation = new Animation();
                var scaleUpAnimation = new Animation(v => startButton.Scale = v, 1, 2, Easing.SpringIn);
                var rotateAnimation = new Animation(v => startButton.Rotation = v, 0, 360);
                var scaleDownAnimation = new Animation(v => startButton.Scale = v, 2, 1, Easing.SpringOut);

                parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, scaleUpAnimation);
                parentAnimation.Add(0, 1, rotateAnimation);
                parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, scaleDownAnimation);

                parentAnimation.Commit(startButton, "ChildAnimations", 16, 4000, null);
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Login());
            };

                public static async Task Sleep(int ms)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(ms);
                }
```

Comment: Good effort.. are you try the drag & drop feature? If yes please answer my question it have 100 bounty now http://stackoverflow.com/q/39220188/3879847