# How to make drag and drop in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have different controls in my XAML page which consists of charts in Xamarin.Forms. The functionality that I want to achieve is to make a long press on each chart, then drag and drop the chart to another place.

I am taking this as an example : https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2018/03/17/re-order-listview-items-with-drag-drop-ii/

But I dont have a listview in my XAML page.

How can I achieve this in XF ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag & Drop in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220188/drag-drop-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Draggable View, and put inside your Images / Graphs or whatever.

A good tutorial can be followed [here](http://www.xamboy.com/2017/08/23/draggable-view-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I have the components arranged in grid layout. How can I move them on a long press, like replacing their position in the grid ?